# Parse error when fetching html via Firebase to React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, cors, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a cloud function endpoint with Firebase from which I can fetch html as a string. The "amazing" idea is to display thet HTML page inside a React component with a fetch. Here is the Firebase express implementation:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const app = express();

app.get('/page3', (request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    response.send(
          '<div><p>Det är en sida</p><section><h1>Return of the King</h1><h2><span>A Long-Expected Party</span></h2><p><br></br></p><p>When Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End announced</p><p>Bilbo was very rich and for fame, wealth.</p><p>‘It will have to be paid for,’ they said. ‘It isn’t natural, and trouble will come of it!’</p><p><br></br></p><p><br></br></p><p><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Note: Look at this link to understand more</span>: <a href="www.svt.se" target="_blank">svt.se</a></p><p><br></br></p><p><br></br></p><p>‘A very nice well-spoken gentlehobbit is Mr. Bilbo, as I’ve always said,’ the Gaffer declared. With perfect truth: for Bilbo was very polite to him.</p><p>‘But what about this Frodo that lives with him?’ asked Old Noakes of Bywater. ‘Baggins is his name, but he’s more than half a Brandybuck, they say.’</p><p><br></br></p><p>‘And and right agin the Old Forest.’</p><p>‘Very much like Mr. Bilbo, Baggins; there was never much to tell of him, till he was drownded.’</p><p><br></br></p></section></div>'
      )
    });  
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Inside the React app I just want to fetch and parse the html string provided by the endpoint and then try to log it. The error I am getting is:

```
<parseerror style= "display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black">
    <h3> This page contains the following errors: </h3>
    <div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px"> error on line 1 at column 1:     Extra content at the end of the document
    </div>
```

And after that a yellow warning in Chrome:

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://easye-9364e.firebaseapp... with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/56 for more details.
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution that works. My problem was in the client side fetch handling here(fetchOptions) where I used no-cors.

```
const [myFetchedHtml, setMyFetchedHtml] = useState('');
const fetchOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
};

// Html Fetch via Google cloudFunction
  useEffect(() => fetch(urlCloudFuncPage3, fetchOptions)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then((html) => {
      const parser = new DOMParser();
      const doc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
      const docDiv = doc.querySelector('div').innerHTML;
      return docDiv;
    })
    .then(docDiv => setMyFetchedHtml(docDiv))
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Failed to fetch: ', err);
    }), []);

  const createMarkup = () => ({ __html: myFetchedHtml });
```

And then use it inside component render return like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />
```

Answer (score 2):

Your missing the line:

`app.use(cors);`

before `app.get()`

So your code should look like:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const app = express();

app.use(cors);
app.get('/page3', (request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    response.send(
          '<div><p>Det är en sida</p><section><h1>Return of the King</h1><h2><span>A Long-Expected Party</span></h2><p><br></br></p><p>When Mr. Bilbo Baggins of Bag End announced</p><p>Bilbo was very rich and for fame, wealth.</p><p>‘It will have to be paid for,’ they said. ‘It isn’t natural, and trouble will come of it!’</p><p><br></br></p><p><br></br></p><p><span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);">Note: Look at this link to understand more</span>: <a href="www.svt.se" target="_blank">svt.se</a></p><p><br></br></p><p><br></br></p><p>‘A very nice well-spoken gentlehobbit is Mr. Bilbo, as I’ve always said,’ the Gaffer declared. With perfect truth: for Bilbo was very polite to him.</p><p>‘But what about this Frodo that lives with him?’ asked Old Noakes of Bywater. ‘Baggins is his name, but he’s more than half a Brandybuck, they say.’</p><p><br></br></p><p>‘And and right agin the Old Forest.’</p><p>‘Very much like Mr. Bilbo, Baggins; there was never much to tell of him, till he was drownded.’</p><p><br></br></p></section></div>'
      )
    });  
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Thanks @Constantin Beer. I did not have to add your suggested line but helped me to look att the client side where I added ```const fetchOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
  };``` and used in the fetch: ```let res = await fetch(urlCloudFunc, fetchOptions); ``` And it worked:)